# Python based GUI with some GIS capabilities

Tags: qgis, python, gui

I would like to construct a Python based GUI which has basic GIS visualization capability. This capability should include:

1) importing OpenSteetMap

2) importing shapefiles/rasters

3) turning layers on and off

4) zooming, panning etc

I was looking into packages like `qt`, `tkinter` or `mpl_toolkits`. I was able to plot a shapefile using `mpl_toolkits.Basemap` but I have the impression it is not the most suitable tool for this kind of application... Any ideas?

Comment: You can use QGIS for this - it has all those capabilities (and more) and a python API so you can build standalone apps using the MapCanvas widget using the Qt toolkit.

Comment: Nice. That definitely gives me something to chew on. Can you build web apps with the qgis API? Like can you load up the MapCanvas as part of a WMS/WPS?

Comment: I'm not sure, and that's way out of scope of your original question - try asking another question.

Comment: I can see how mapcanvas can cover 2) importing rasters and shapefiles and 4) zoming/panning. However I don't see how it can cover 1) importing OpenStreetMap and 3) turning layers on and off. Isn't it just a canvas that represents what's loaded up in QGIS?

Comment: You can build web map with QGIS API but with help of some additional tools like [nextgis web](http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngweb_dev/doc/developer/toc.html) or qgisserver

Comment: how about items 2) and 4)?

Comment: **Item 2** - http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngweb/source/layers.html, **item 4** - http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngweb/source/webmaps_client.html - you may try all of this on [nextgis.com](https://my.nextgis.com/signup/?next=/webgis/) freely. All this features available via REST API too.

Comment: Now your talking about web apps... the question is on construction of a GUI locally, not as part of a web service.

Comment: You wrote "Can you build web apps with the qgis API?" - and I answered. For desktop - just see https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/

Comment: Specifically which parts talk about items 2) and 4) in the cook book?

Comment: **item 2** - https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html **item 4** - https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/canvas.html#embedding-map-canvas

Comment: Thats for doing stuff in the default GUI. I want to build my own GUI but with similar functionality (adding, removing layers etc)

Comment: You are not quite right - this is about single python GUI application with QGIS functionality (PyQt is preferable). https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#python-applications